# MySQL / PHP preg_replace and KEEP accents and spaces

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, diacritics

I have a MySQL database, being fed data from a PHP powered form. The table columns are collated as utf8_bin, the connection charset is set at utf8, as is the HTML.

After extensive Googling, I cannot seem to find any clear way of using preg_replace to strip unwanted characters (and numbers) but keep upper/lowercase accents, umlauts and spaces. I've cobbled together something that seems to work - but I don't understand it at all, so have no idea how secure it is. Hence the doubling up with the escape clause:

```
$lname = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e","", $lname);
        $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);
```

What I really need is the kind of clause that could take the following name (mine, as an example): "Éamonn Mac Lochlainn" and store it as such, rather than "c389616d6f6e6eMacLochlainn" I've looked at strip_tags also, allowing "ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú". Is that the way forward?

Any help - and, in particular, explanations of what's going on in this snippet (the \w+ bits)- would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\w` is a word character according to the current locale. If that is set correctly for all the data: no problem. If your locale is not enough, you could say all letters & whitespace are valid:

```
$lname = preg_replace('/[^\s\p{L}]/u','',$lname);
```

For more information about `\w`, see [Escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)
For more information about unicode properties (the `\p` in combination with the `/u` switch), see [Unicode Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

You seem to do a bit more then just validating characters, also stripping HTML tags. `strip_tags` would work for this indeed (do it before the replace).

Comment: Thanks Wrikken! Is there a place that lists all of these parameters (\s, \p, etc.) and where and how to use them? I mean, I assume your example strips slashes, dashes and dots - but I don't know that for a fact. If there was a tut somewhere, I could taylor my own in the future.

Comment: Heh, was already editing them in before you asked them, in the answer now :) If you are validating names however, dashes and quotes are used in the names of a lot of languages...

Answer (score 5):

This solution may work for you if you only want to keep upper and lower case alpha characters in either french or english:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$str="Conférence ministérielle sur la francophonie canadienne - Éamonn Mac Lochlainn";
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ  ]/",'',$str);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The echo'd response is:

```
Conférence ministérielle sur la francophonie canadienne Éamonn Mac Lochlainn
```